# PAW duplicated documents retain query output between documents, is this supposed to happen?

Tags: paw-app

I have a PAW document that duplicated into two different documents, app A and app B.  The files use environments and variables.  When I have both open if I do a REST call in app A then switch to app B the results from the call in A are displayed in the results output are in B.  If I refresh the REST call in app B, then I see the results in the output of app A.  My guess, is there is a setting to a file location that is being updated when I do a REST call and since the documents are duplicated they are sharing this location.  If this is the case, can I update this file location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because responses (HTTP exchanges) are stored in an independent location, in order to keep your actual files clean of the request/response history. For that, we reference responses by an unique identifier of the request that generated them. Duplicating files manually tricks this system...

As a quick workaround, I suggest that in one of the documents, you group all requests together, duplicate the group, and then delete the original group. This will assign new identifiers to requests, and fix your issue. (It will also break links between requests, used in Request/Response dynamic values...).

A quick screencast to explain this: http://cl.ly/2S3c46122k3s

Comment: Am I using the File -> Duplicate menu option incorrectly?  It seems that this would happen anytime a file is duplicated.  Is the better process to create groups for each application that shares similar REST calls?

Comment: I'd rather select the requests/groups you want to copy, hit Copy (right-click "Copy", or Cmd+C) and paste those in the new document. Alternatively, just keep all in one document, and organize requests with groups.